# Vue deleting a nested loop element causes an error

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

So I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <FormulateForm>
    <FormulateInput type="group" name="rules">
      <div v-for="(fields, index) in rule" :key="index">
        <div>
          <div>
            <font-awesome-icon
              icon="times"
              @click.prevent="deleteRule(index)"
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <div
              v-for="(additional, pos) in fields.additionals"
              :key="additional"
            > //ITERATES ALL SUBRULES THAT A RULE POSSES
              <div>
                <font-awesome-icon
                  icon="times"
                  @click.prevent="deleteAdditional(index, additional, pos)"
                />
              </div>

              <FormulateInput
                label="Additional Type"
                :options="additionalsTypeOptions"
                v-model="additionals[additional].type"
                value="subRule1"
                type="select"
              />

              <div v-if="additionals[additional].type === 'subRule1'">
                <h2>SubRule1</h2>
              </div>
              <div v-else-if="additionals[additional].type === 'subRule2'">
                <h2>SubRule2</h2>
              </div>

              <div v-else-if="additionals.type === 'subRule3'">
                <h2>SubRule3</h2>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button @click.prevent="addAdditionals(index)">
              Add Additionals
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button @click.prevent="addMore()">Add Rules</button>
      </div>
    </FormulateInput>
  </FormulateForm>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'rule-set'
  data() {
    return {
      additionals: [], //STORES ALL SUBRULE OBJECTS

      rule: [
        {
          mainRule: '',
          additionals: [], //THIS HOLDS ALL INDEX OF THE ADDITIONALS WHICH SERVES LIKE A FOREIGN KEY
        },
      ],

      additionalsTypeOptions: [
        { value: 'subRule1', label: 'Sub Rule 1' },
        { value: 'subRule2', label: 'Sub Rule 2' },
        { value: 'subRule3', label: 'Sub Rule 3' },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addMore() {
      const fields = {
        mainRule: '',
        additionals: [],
      };

      this.rule.push(fields);
    },

    addAdditionals(index) {
      const pushedIndex =
        this.additionals.push({
          type: 'subRule1',
          value: '',
        }) - 1;

      this.rule[index].additionals.push(pushedIndex);
    },

    deleteRule(index) {
      this.$delete(this.rule, index);
    },

    deleteAdditional(ruleIndex, additionalIndex, ruleArrayIndex) {
      this.$delete(this.rule[ruleIndex].additionals, ruleArrayIndex);

      this.$delete(this.additionals, additionalIndex);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

It's simple enough a user can add rules and add subrules to thoserules. Adding and deletion work fine however there is one particular use case that throws an error

```
Rule1
 -subrule1-> DELETING THIS WILL THROW AN ERROR
 -subrule2-> DELETING THIS WILL WORK  

Rule2
 -subrule1   
 -subrule2
 -subrule3
 -subrule4-> DELETING THIS WILL WORK THE OTHERS WILL THROW AN ERROR
```

Whenever it throws the follwing error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
```

Whenever I delete anything that is not the latest subrule it throws an error which is on the v-if statement in determining which type of subrule it is. I tried using this.$delete and vue.delete and it doesn't seem to work. I also tried this.$forceupdate() and it doesn't work as well. Could this be a key problem? or is there a vue operation that is made specific for nested v-for?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an element from Array must be done with `Array.splice()` method - e.g. if you want to delete subrule 1 on rule 1 you must call `deleteAdditional(this.rules[0], 0)`

```js
deleteAdditional(ruleObject, additionalIndex)
{
  ruleObject.additionals.splice(additionalIndex, 1);
}
```

`this.$delete` and `Object.delete` work on Objects - not on Arrays.

Comment: Here's what I did:

I implemented your solution and bound the select type to the additional. The deletion is now working fine but the v-if is not detecting the type

Comment: If it is the 3rd `v-if` - then it is because its definition differs from the other 2 `v-if`s.

Comment: upon further investigation it seems that vue has a problem accessing object fields inside array of objects like ex.   additionals[additional].type it will throw and error on type but if you do a map on additionals[additional] and return it works

Comment: `additional` is expected to be an index inside `additionals` - so if it is beyond the array's length it will refer to UNDEFINED.